# Class not found exception when using Java class in c#

Tags: java, .net, deserialization, classnotfoundexception, ikvm

I convert a **`java's class`** to **`dll`** using **`IKVM`**, by making a **`jar file`** for the this class and then I used **`IKVM`** to make the conversion operation. this operation is done successfully without errors or warnings. then I add the (DLL) with an `'IKVM.GNU.Classpath.dll'` and `'IKVM.Runtime.dll'` (DLLs) to my project. then I rebuilt the project, up to that point no errors, no warnings, no crashes happened. but when I tried to deserialized an arraylist of object from it is type, I get an exception is : **`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "MyClass" not found in java.lang.ClassLoader... my deserliazation`**.  code is :

```
 object deserializedObject = null;               
 java.io.ObjectInputStream ina = new java.io.ObjectInputStream(new java.io.FileInputStream(@"D:\130043674485690000.txt"));
 deserializedObject = ina.readObject();
 ina.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: you should use the current version of IKVM for new projects. The file name show that you use a very old version of IKVM.

Second: you need to use all dlls from the IKVM. If all is working then you can remove some of the not used dlls.

Third: if you does reference the classes of your dll/jar file statically then you need load it dynamically. See the [wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Convert_a_jar_file_to_a_dll_and_use_it_as_library) for details.